# UITtextView in UIScrollView

Tags: iphone

Created `UITextView` in `UIScrollView`

```
scrollView = [[UIScrollView alloc]init];

self.textView = [[[UITextView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10, 225, 300, 100)]autorelease];

self.textView.textColor = [UIColor brownColor];

self.textView.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Georgia-Bold" size:14];

self.textView.textAlignment = UITextAlignmentCenter;

self.textView.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithHue:2.0/12 saturation:2.0 brightness:4.0/10 alpha:1.0];

self.textView.editable = NO;

self.textView.textAlignment =  UITextAlignmentCenter;

self.textView.text = @"this is uitext. this is uitext.....";

[scrollView addSubview:textView];
```

all i m able to see is black screen why i m not seeing my textview.

Thanks for help.

Comment: where do you push, display or add the scrollView itself?

i recon this is in one of your viewcontrollers. so you will first have to clip the scrollview to your view (as subview or pushed view). this should solve it.

Comment: or create the scrollView in your interface and connect it with a outlet to your viewcontroller =)

Comment: i m not using interfacebuilder but doing it programmtically

Comment: ol then please provide the code that shows where and how you show 'scrollView'. because i suspect it to be missing and that would explain your problem :-)

Comment: Add this line after addSubview in your above code NSLog(@"ScrollView : %@\nSubviews : %@",scrollView ,[scrollView  subviews]); wht does it print? Are you able to see your scrollView? its frame is not still not set?

Comment: what about `[self.view addSubview:scrollView]`?

Answer (score 2):

Try out this code

```
[self.scrollView addSubview:textView];
```

Hope this helps you

Answer (score 0):

Probably solved months ago but this should probably do it (for the people that google and find this question)

```
UIScrollView *scrollView = [[UIScrollView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 460)];
[self.view addSubview:scrollView];
```

Answer (score 0):

```
UIScrollView *scrollView = [[UIScrollView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 460)];
[self.view addSubview:scrollView];
self.textView = [[[UITextView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10, 225, 300, 100)]autorelease];

self.textView.textColor = [UIColor brownColor];

self.textView.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Georgia-Bold" size:14];

self.textView.textAlignment = UITextAlignmentCenter;

self.textView.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithHue:2.0/12 saturation:2.0 brightness:4.0/10 alpha:1.0];

self.textView.editable = NO;

self.textView.textAlignment =  UITextAlignmentCenter;

self.textView.text = @"this is uitext. this is uitext.....";

[scrollView addSubview:textView];
```